# How do I show the value of LastLogonTime from a mailbox query

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

How can I show the **value** of the attribute `LastLogonTime`?

```
function Get-MailboxesNotLoggedOnTo {
    param(
        [int]$days = 90
    )

    $mailboxes = Get-Mailbox -ResultSize 500
    $mailboxes | Where-Object {
        (Get-MailboxStatistics $_).LastLogonTime -and
        (Get-MailboxStatistics $_).LastLogonTime -le (Get-Date).AddDays(-$days)
    } | FT DisplayName, Alias, ServerName, LastLogonTime
}
```

Comment: Your code should already do that. Please show us how the output you get is different from the output you expect.

Comment: nop, the attribuut LastLogonTime shows a empty value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because `Get-Mailbox` does not return a property called `LastLogonTime`. `Get-MailboxStatistics` does. What you need to do is add the timestamp as a property of your output

```
$mailboxes = Get-Mailbox -ResultSize 200
$mailboxes | Where-Object {
    (Get-MailboxStatistics $_).LastLogonTime -and
    (Get-MailboxStatistics $_).LastLogonTime -le (Get-Date).AddDays(-$days)
} | ForEach-Object {Add-Member -InputObject $_ -MemberType NoteProperty -Name LastLogonTime -Value (Get-MailboxStatistics $_).LastLogonTime -PassThru} |
Select DisplayName, Alias, ServerName, LastLogonTime
```

Using `Add-Member` we can fill in the missing piece. The one issue I have with this is the multiple calls to `Get-MailboxStatistics` which im working on improving now. Should be something closer to this.

```
$checkDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-90)
$mailboxes = Get-Mailbox -ResultSize 200 
$mailboxes | ForEach-Object{
    $stats = Get-MailboxStatistics $_
    If ($stats.LastLogonTime -and ($stats.LastLogonTime -le $checkDate)){
        Add-Member -InputObject $_ -MemberType NoteProperty -Name LastLogonTime -Value $stats.LastLogonTime -PassThru
    }
} | Select DisplayName, Alias, ServerName, LastLogonTime
```

The extra calls to `Get-MailboxStatistics` would make it slower. Reduced the call to only the one. Still using `Add-Member` with `-PassThru` which just pipes out to a select statement. This should be a more efficient approach.

Comment: Thanks Matt. I know that get-mailbox has no property LastLogonTime, and Get-Mailboxstatistics does.
I did not know you could use forEach-Object with Add-Member...

Comment: @lander You had output from `Get-Mailbox` in the pipe. While you were checking properties from `Get-MailboxStatitics` you were not changing the data in pipe.